# Windows Forms: preserving scroll position after redraw

Tags: .net, winforms, scroll, redraw

I am building a simple image browser/viewer application in Windows Forms.

The main Form contains a Panel control with AutoScroll enabled to create a scrollable content area for the images beneath the main application MenuStrip.

Inside this Panel are dynamically placed one or more UserControl objects that I have defined. Each of these contains a GroupBox (to display a title for each group of thumbnails), which in turn contains some buttons and a FlowLayoutPanel which is populated with one or more PictureBox objects displaying the image thumbnails.

Each thumbnail can be clicked to open the selected image at full-size, or as close to it as possible within the application window. This is achieved by dynamically generating a PictureBox control which occupies the whole window, with a z-index value that causes it to display above the thumbnail grid, thus obscuring it.

The problem I have is that both when I create and destroy the overlaid PictureBox control, the underlying Panel control containing the thumbnails redraws itself, and this resets its scroll position to the top, which is annoying if you have previously scrolled down at all.

Weirdly, sometimes the scroll position is preserved, and I cannot determine a pattern to explain the inconsistent behaviour.

Can anyone suggest a neat solution to prevent this happening? Or will I need to inspect the scroll position of the Panel and programmatically set it back to the same value after it has redrawn?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?  I have a similar problem of trying to persevere the scroll position of a flowlayoutpanel full of custom controls after a redraw.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the Panel isn't necessary.  I'm guessing you have the FlowLayoutPanel's AutoSize set to true.

Try using just the FlowLayoutPanel since it will provide the scrolling for you with the default AutoSize = false.

Comment: Thanks but the Panel is necessary - I've edited the question to clarify the hierarchy of objects I am using.

Comment: @BestMamguEver But a FlowLayoutPanel is scrollable.  Why not use that?

Comment: Because I want the application window to contain multiple groups of thumbnails, each with its own set of labels and associated controls, but I don't want multiple scrollbars - just the single one at the side of the main window

Comment: @BestMamguEver Picture might help.

Comment: OK, [this is the custom UserControl](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/13860553/UserControl.jpg). The FLowLayoutPanel itself is the one currently selected. I will have one or more of these controls in the main window, and want any scrolling to be handled by the main window's scrollbar.